# ¿Cómo imprimir un número para que tenga ceros a la izquierda?

Tags: c

Tengo un programa en el que tengo que introducir una hora y necesito que esa hora se imprima por pantalla. Este es mi código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
   int horas, minutos;
   printf("Introduzca una hora (separado por espacios): ");
   scanf("%d %d", &horas, &minutos); //No incluyo los do-while para que el código no sea largo
   printf("La hora introducida es %d:%d", horas, minutos);
   return 0;
}
```

Necesito que cuando se introduzca una hora, si las horas o los minutos son menores que 10, me imprima un 0 a la izquierda del número. Por ejemplo, si introduzco `9 5`, tengo que hacer que imprima por pantalla `09:05` y no `9:5`. ¿Qué tendría que hacer?

Comment: Tu mismo resolviste tu duda, solo agrega dos if que validen si las horas y minutos son menores a 10, siendo el caso imprime el formato con un cero a la izuquierda ->  "La hora introducida es 0%d:0%d".

Comment: @denso ¿No existe ningún formato que pueda poner entre `%` y `d` para que me lo imprima directamente sin hacer ningún if?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("%02d:%02d", horas, minutos);
```

El 0 es el caracter de relleno y el 2 el número mínimo de dígitos